# How to eliminate variables when they are time-dependent?

Tags: symbolic, difference-equations

i really hope you can help me with the following. I want to do something like this

`Eliminate[{y[t] == 5*x[t + 1], x[t] == 5*z[t]}, x[t]]`

to get

`y[t]==25*z[t+1]`

Obviously, this does not work. Does someone of you know what needs to be done in such a case?

Comment: Would you be able to use a replacement rule, as in `y[t] == 5*x[t + 1] /. {x[t_] -> 5*z[t]}`, which yields `y[t] == 25 z[1 + t]`?

Comment: Of course, this works. But my actual problem is a system of equations with lagrange multipliers that depend on t, t+1, t+2 and i need to eliminate them. If i use eliminate it seemingly does not write an equation a period ahead to use it to eliminate a multiplier in t+1. Can you follow?

Comment: I didn't really expect this to work but it did: `Eliminate[Flatten@{y[t] == 5*x[t + 1], x[t] == 5*z[t] /. {{t -> t}, {t -> t + 1}, {t -> t + 2}}}, x[t] /. {{t -> t}, {t -> t + 1}, {t -> t + 2}}]` -- Might need another MWE that better represents the issues you face.  -- Tip: use @user to notify "user" of your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Paradoxically perhaps, one can get rid of them by solving for them. the idea is to replace them after solving so that all solutions are in terms of `x[t]`. These then get equated.

Step 1: find all the `x[...]` and solve for them.

```
eqns = {y[t] == 5*x[t + 1], x[t] == 5*z[t]};
xvars = Cases[eqns, x[_], Infinity];
xsols = First[Solve[eqns, xvars]]

(* Out[1028]= {x[1 + t] -> y[t]/5, x[t] -> 5 z[t]} *)
```

Step 2: Transform all solutions into terms of `x[t]`.

```
updateT[expr_, x_, t_] := Module[{tvals},
  tvals = Union[Cases[expr, x[t + j_] :> j, Infinity]];
  If[Length[tvals] != 1, Return[expr]];
  expr /. t -> t - tvals[[1]]
  ]

newsols = Map[updateT[#, x, t] &, xsols]

(* Out[1032]= {x[t] -> 1/5 y[-1 + t], x[t] -> 5 z[t]} *)
```

Step 3: Equate right hand sides of these solutions.

```
neweqns = Apply[Equal, newsols[[All, 2]]]

(* Out[1033]= 1/5 y[-1 + t] == 5 z[t] *)
```

Alternatively, now use `Eliminate`.

```
Eliminate[Apply[Equal, newsols, {1}], x[t]]

(* Out[1043]= 25 z[t] == y[-1 + t] *)
```

The point is to let `Solve` do the hard work of "triangulating" the `x[...]` variables rather than trying to be clever about substituting by hand.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple substitution t->t+1, that works very well

```
Eliminate[{y[t] == 5*x[t + 1], x[t] == 5*z[t] /. t -> t + 1}, x[t + 1]]

(*     25 z[1 + t] == y[t]     *)
```